# Why is Mathematica telling me that two equal sequences are unequal?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-test

These two sequences are identical:

```
a[n_] := 1/Gamma[(1 - n)/2]

c[n_] := If[EvenQ[n], 1/Gamma[(1 - n)/2], 0]

Table[a[n], {n, 0, 1000}] == Table[c[n], {n, 0, 1000}]
(* True *)
```

Nevertheless, `FullSimplify[a[n] == c[n], {n \[Element] Integers, n >= 0}]` returns `False`. Why is this?

v12.0.0.0

Comment: The `EvenQ` problem aside: Is `a[1]` undefined or zero?  Mathematically, `1` is not in the domain.  Computationally, `Gamma` returns `ComplexInfinity`, and `1/ComplexInfinity` evaluates to `0`. Consider: `Reduce[FunctionDomain[1/Gamma[(1 - n)/2], n] && n \[Element] Integers]`.  Also, this returns the "mathematical" result: `c[n_] := If[(1 - n)/2 \[NotElement] Integers, 1/Gamma[(1 - n)/2], 0]; FullSimplify[a[n] == c[n], {n \[Element] Integers, n >= 0}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EvenQ[n]` is `False` for symbolic `n`. `EvenQ` will only return `True` for literal even integers, and `False` for everything else. It is a convention in Mathematica that any function ending in `Q` returns either `True` or `False` for any input.

Think of `EvenQ` as a function in the programming sense, not the mathematical sense.

You can detect this problem by looking at what `c[n]` evaluates to (as opposed to e.g. what `c[2]` evaluates to).

Generally, a possible solution could be `c[n_] := Piecewise[{{1/Gamma[(1 - n)/2], Mod[n, 2] == 0}}, 0]`. This won't quite work here. `FullSimplify` will return `Mod[n,2] == 0` as it can't figure out that `a[n] == 0` for any odd `n`.

Comment: Symbolic processing, `Simplify` and friends, cannot generally reason about things that are functions in the programming sense.

Comment: @JohnDoty It's not that they cannot reason, but that `FullSimplify` never even sees that `EvenQ`. Evaluate `c[n]`. There is no `EvenQ`  there. It's gone, evaluated to `False`.

Comment: One might imagine an easy fix: define `c[n_Integer] := ...`. But then, `Simplify` has no way to look inside the definition and reason about the algorithm.